# How to add master page to already created webform?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have a asp.net  webform application. Now I have to add master page in this application, but I don’t know how to merge or add new created master page with old webforms?  How to handle html in webforms like `<head>` , `<body>` ? Any link in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- Define the fixed elements in your design, and put them inside the newly created master page

2- Define the dynamic ones, and add `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` for them ( most commonly one for `HEAD`, one for main content in your `BODY` , and one for side content "*if applicable*")

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CphHead" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

3- In your pages, add `MasterPageFile="~/MASTER_PAGE_PATH"` inside the Page directive.

4- Add `asp:Content` sections inside your pages which will hold the dynamic content in your pages, and don't forget to reference the correct `ContentPlaceholder ID`.

```
    <asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="CphHead" runat="server">

       // Your content goes here...

    </asp:Content>
```

5- Copy your page content inside these `asp:content` sections, and BOOOOM....you are done.

Comment: my old webforms have html tag like form head body style etc how to handle these?

Comment: like i said above, just put your HEAD section inside the HEAD content section. and regarding your BODY section, you should know the different sections inside and decide what needs to go in a content section, and what should remain static inside your master page.

if this is not clear yet, Kindly post the full contents of one of your pages, then i may post some suggested solution for you.

Answer (score 5):

at the top of the new page in the '<%@ page @>' tag add 'MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"'
then add the needed placeholders

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

of course modify these to the names you are using

Comment: my old webforms have html tag like `form` `head` `body` `style` etc how to handle these?

Comment: the HeadContent contains everything inside the <head> html tag. and the main contains everything from <body>. If you look at your masterpage you should see those tags there. So you won't need them in your old page anymore bacause the masterpage surrounds your old page with those tags. Any other content like <form>, <table>, ... should just go into the content area.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the content holder *tag* in master page. So when you  add **'MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"'** then  you able to add content of other pages.